# Displaying images like google drive on React front-end by retrieving from Node.js back-end

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Want to display images inside folders in React webpage by retrieving from Nodejs back-end.

Answer (score 0):

Store the path to the  in the database. After that you retrieve that it in your server side code and return it in a json format.
You can then input this in the browser like this
http://localhost:300/retrieve_picture to see the json output like this:

```
[
{
"picture":/path-to-picture/pic.jpg",
" image-title":"My lovely picture",
}
]
```

In you react code,you can make a call to that back end API to display the image
React code:

```
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state={
photo:[ ]
}
}
//Making call to the API
fetch("http://localhost:300/retrieve_picture",
{
"method": " GET",
"Content-Type":" application/json",
}
).
then (res=>res.json())
/*Updating the state to render json output into the empty array*/
.then (data=>
this.setState({
photo:data
})
)
.catch(err=>console.log(err);
//You now render it like this
render(){
return (
<div>
{
this.state.photo.map(p=>
<div>
<h3>{p.image-title}</h3>
<img src={`http://localhost:300${t.picture} }\>
</div>
)
<\div>
)
}
```